# Error while connecting to virtual machine in VMware workstation 9

Tags: vmware-workstation

When i connect to virtual machine it shows this message "VMware workstation is unable to provide all of the graphics features expected by this VM. The graphics hardware, graphics drivers or version of VMware software might have changed since this VM was booted" 
I am connecting to windows server 2003 virtual machine. My host machine is windows 7 32bit. I have nvidia Geforce graphics card. I am using VMware 9 version.
Please help me how do i solve this error